# Setup Rails 3.1 and Postgresql on Snow Leopard

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-3.1, osx-snow-leopard

I have spent countless number of hours trying to setup PostgreSql on my Intel Mac.

I am able to install Rails and all but PostgreSql would not get installed on my Mac.

Anybody has any solution or any tutorial which I can follow to install it ??

P.S. I just started using Mac as my development machine. I have been using Windows before that !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok I had to do a little more research with a fresh mind and I am now able to solve the problem myself. Here is the solution :

Install Homebrew using this command :

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSLk https://gist.github.com/raw/323731/install_homebrew.rb)"
```

Once installed write this in your terminal :

```
brew install postgres
```

If this is your first install ( which was the case with me ) than type this in terminal after the above step:

```
$ initdb /usr/local/var/postgres
```

To start the postgresql type this in terminal:

```
pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log start
```

After the above step type this :

```
ps auxwww | grep postgres
```

If the result of the above command in terminal looks like this than that means the postgresql is installed correctly :

```
26000   0.0  0.1  2445860   1556   ??  Ss    1:59AM   0:00.05 postgres: autovacuum launcher process
25999   0.0  0.0  2445728    512   ??  Ss    1:59AM   0:00.15 postgres: wal writer process
25998   0.0  0.0  2445728    912   ??  Ss    1:59AM   0:00.21 postgres: writer process  

25996   0.0  0.1  2445728   2508   ??  S     1:59AM   0:00.15 /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.0.4/bin/postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres

26257   0.0  0.0  2435548      0 s000  R+    2:19AM   0:00.00 grep postgres
```

**Create a user and database:**

```
createuser username

createdb -Ousername -Eutf8 databasename
```

To login to postgresql use this command:

```
psql -U username databasename
```

If you are using it with rails you can install the gem like this :

```
sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install --no-ri --no-rdoc pg
```

If you would like to stop the PostgreSQL service use this command :

```
pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres stop -s -m fast
```

Hope this will help others in saving the time of going through different resources to come with the solution like I did :)

Answer (score 2):

Try using [Cinderella](https://github.com/atmos/cinderella). That will give you the whole stack (including MongoDB, Redis, and a whole bunch of other stuff) in one nice neat bundle in `~/Developer`. You're better off using custom builds of all your development tools so that you don't have to worry about what version of anything comes with the system and what an upgrade might to do your OS.

References:

- [Cinderella on Github](https://github.com/atmos/cinderella)
- [Cinderella Homepage](http://www.atmos.org/cinderella/)

Comment: Cinderalla looks cool ... I have not seen that before. Thanks for posting and I'll have to check that out!

Answer (score 1):

A few other notes to add to your instructions:

There is a good post at [Russ Brooks Blog on installation](http://russbrooks.com/2010/11/25/install-postgresql-9-on-os-x) which validates much of what you have above.

There are a set of admin tools available at [pgadmin.org](http://pgadmin.org/) which will allow you to browse your database through a simple GUI on the Mac

If you use the admin tools you should install the instrumentation pack with the following:

```
psql -d postgres < /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.0.4/share/postgresql/contrib/adminpack.sql
```

where the exact command obviously depends on the version of postgresql you are using.

If you are using postgres with rails and bundler then make sure the "pg" gem is in your gem file and run bundler with the following command immediately after you add it:

```
env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" bundle install
```

This will do the same as your 'gem install' command above.  After you run it for the first time you no longer need to use the 'env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64"' when you run bundler.

Comment: `CREATE EXTENSION adminpack` is the way to do this on newer (9.2, etc.) PostgreSQL installations.

Answer (score 0):

I have used [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/install.php) for most of my server/low level program installations (PostgreSQL, MySQL, etc.). If you choose to go that route, you can then follow this [blog post/tutorial](http://www.gregbenedict.com/2009/08/31/installing-postgresql-on-snow-leopard-10-6/) on installing PostgreSQL via MacPorts onto your Mac. One thing to note on the PostgreSQL link: when following along, change the instances of 83 to 90. For example, you will see this in his steps:

```
sudo port install postgresql83 postgresql83-server
```

You can instead, type this to get the newest version of PostgreSQL

```
sudo port install postgresql90 postgresql90-server
```

I would also recommend grabbing a program such as [Navicat for PostgreSQL Lite](https://www.navicat.com/en/download/navicat-for-mysql). It's free and nice to have to manage your local PostgreSQL DBs.

If you don't want to go with MacPorts, there's a similar alternative called HomeBrew that's quite popular ... I'm just too lazy to switch from MacPorts :).

Answer (score 0):

I had luck downloading and installing it straight from the site:

http://www.postgresql.org/download/macosx